# How to show formatted price according to store wise currency in admin(Custom module)?

Tags: admin, price, currency, format

I have 2 websites in my magento. I have created one custom extension. In custom extension, i have form to fill which have firstname , last name, product price, store id.

Website 1 currency = USD (Deafult currency)
Website 2 currency = EUR

When i submit form data will be saved in custom table and shown in custom admin grid. I want to show price according to the store wise entry.

If i fill form website 1 then my price needs to show like $54.00 and if i fill form from website 2 then price needs to show like €10.00.

I have used below code to show formatted price with currency in admin.

```
<?php
 
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;
 
 
class Customprice extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
 
    protected $priceCurrency; 
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
 
    public function getCurrencyWithFormat($price)
    {
        return $this->priceCurrency->format($price,true,2);
    }
}
```

**In website 2 if $price = 10; then according to above code it will be shown like $10.00 but in website 2 it should show like €10.00.**

```
$formmattedPrice = $this->getCurrencyWithFormat($price);
```

I am facing problem only in admin. In front end it shows proper currency according to store wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below way to formatted price according to store wise with proper currency symbol.

Please pass your store id in below helper function to get proper formmatted price.

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Directory\Model\Currency;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $priceHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency
     */
    protected $currency;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Currency $currency = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->priceHelper = $priceHelper;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->currency = $currency ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->create(Currency::class);
    }

    /**
     * get currency code
     *
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return mixed 
     */
    public function getCurrentCurrencyCode($storeId)
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    }  

    /*Get price format */
    public function getFormattedPrice($storeId, $price)
    {
        $currencyCode = $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode($storeId);
        $purchaseCurrency = $this->currency->load($currencyCode);
        return $purchaseCurrency->format($price, [], false);
    }
}
```

**Please use above function getFormattedPrice($storeId, $price) and pass store id , price in this function to get store wise currency in admin.**

Thanks!